# Is there any Alternative to "IN" statement in T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

Consider this code snippet:

```
SELECT 
    vbs.SKUID, SKUName, SUM(vbs.Quantity) AS Qty
FROM   
    BatchStocks AS vbs
WHERE  
    vbs.SKUID IN (Here i have almost 12000 SKU)
    AND vbs.StoreID IN (%q)
    AND vbs.StockType = %n
GROUP BY
    vbs.SKUID, vbs.SKUName
```

In the `where` condition, i have almost 12000 SKUID which take much time to execute statement. Can you please suggest how I can improve this query?

Comment: Put those 12000 SKUID's into their own table, and just do an `INNER JOIN` ....

Answer (score 5):

you can use `EXISTS()`

put the SKU in a temp table

and

```
WHERE  vbs.SKUID IN (Here i have almost 12000 SKU)
```

change to

```
WHERE  EXISTS
       (
           SELECT *
           FROM   #TEMP x
           WHERE  x.SKUID  = vbs.SKUID 
       )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `Inner Join, EXISTS` instead of IN.
Please refer EXISTS query :

```
SELECT 
    vbs.SKUID, SKUName, SUM(vbs.Quantity) AS Qty
FROM   
    BatchStocks AS vbs
WHERE  
    EXISTS ( select 1 from #TEMPTABLE t on t.SKUID = vbs.SKUID)
    AND vbs.StoreID IN (%q)
    AND vbs.StockType = %n
GROUP BY
    vbs.SKUID, vbs.SKUName
```

Please refer below query for INNER JOIN:

```
SELECT 
    vbs.SKUID, SKUName, SUM(vbs.Quantity) AS Qty
FROM   
    BatchStocks AS vbs
    INNER JOIN #TEMPTABLE t on t.SKUID = vbs.SKUID
WHERE  vbs.StoreID IN (%q)
    AND vbs.StockType = %n
GROUP BY
    vbs.SKUID, vbs.SKUName
```

Comment: Careful with a `JOIN`, if there are any duplicates then 2 (or more) rows would be returned for what should have been a single one.